# Fixing Migrations and Django migrating error

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I wrote migrations to my Django project and then I applied the `make migrations` and `migrate` commands. For Django there is no problem,but when I run the project I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column providers_providerhotel.is_active does not exist
LINE 1: ...hotel"."hash", "providers_providerhotel"."stars", "providers...
                                                             ^

Exception ignored in: <function GEOSGeometry.__del__ at 0x1107fb830>
Traceback (most recent call last):

ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

I think there is problem for adding column to database from my model.And for django , there is no problem it alerts 'I wrote it to database there is no issue'. but it doesn't. Can anybody help to solve it ?

model.py

```
is_active = models.NullBooleanField()
```

003_providerhotel_is_active.py

```
+# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
+# Generated by Django 1.10.5 on 2019-09-12 07:48
+from __future__ import unicode_literals
+
+from django.db import migrations, models
+
+
+class Migration(migrations.Migration):
+
+    dependencies = [
+        ('providers', '0002_auto_20170203_0707'),
+    ]
+
+    operations = [
+        migrations.AddField(
+            model_name='providerhotel',
+            name='is_active',
+            field=models.NullBooleanField(),
+        ),
+    ]
```

providers/**init**.py

```
'is_active': None, }
```

Comment: Have you checked that your migration has been properly applied ? I mean: connect to the database with your commandline client and inspect both the djang_migrations table and your own providers_providerhotel table ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use postgresql

Comment: when I check my migrations every thing is ok but ı think ıt is not connecting with my database and not adding is_active colum django_migrations and providers_providerhotel table